# Publish asp.net project automatically after successful build using post build events

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, post-build-event

I don't know if this is the right way to ask the question.

I have two asp.net projects within one solution and I want to publish these projects after each successful build for the sake of automation to some folder within the solution.

Can this be done using post build events or Power shell scripts ? and how this can be achieved if it's applicable?

I'm using visual studio 2013 on Windows 7